# when is a pytorch custom function needed (rather than only a module)?

Tags: torch, pytorch

Pytorch beginner here! Consider the following custom Module:

```
class Testme(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Testme, self).__init__()

def forward(self, x):
    return x / t_.max(x).expand_as(x)
```

As far as I understand the documentation:
I believe this could also be implemented as a custom `Function`.  A subclass of `Function` requires a `backward()` method, but the
`Module` does not.  As well, in the doc example of a Linear `Module`, it depends on a Linear `Function`:

```
class Linear(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, input_features, output_features, bias=True):
        ...    
    def forward(self, input):
        return Linear()(input, self.weight, self.bias)
```

The question: I do not understand the relation between `Module` and `Function`. In the first listing above (module `Testme`), should it have an associated function? If not, then it is possible to implement this *without* a `backward` method by subclassing Module, so why does a `Function` always require a `backward` method?

Perhaps `Function`s are intended only for functions that are not composed out of existing torch functions? Say differently: maybe modules do not need the associated `Function` if their `forward` method is composed entirely from previously defined torch functions?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This information is gathered and summarised from the official PyTorch Documentaion.

`torch.autograd.Function`really lies at the heart of the autograd package in PyTorch. Any graph you build in PyTorch and any operation you conduct on `Variables` in PyTorch is based on a `Function`. Any function requires an  `__init__(), forward()` and `backward()` method (see more here: http://pytorch.org/docs/notes/extending.html) . This enables PyTorch to compute results and compute gradients for `Variables`.

`nn.Module()`in contrast is really just a convenience for organising your model, your different layers, etc. For example, it organises all the trainable parameters in your model in `.parameters()`and allows you to add another layer to a model easily, etc. etc. It is **not** the place where you define a backward method, because in the `forward()` method, you're supposed to use subclasses of `Function()`, for which you have already defined `backward()`. Hence, if you have specified the order of operations in `forward()`, PyTorch already knows how to back-propagate gradients.

**Now, when should you use what?**

If you have an operation that is just a composition of existing implemented functions in PyTorch (like your thing above), there's really no point adding any subclass to Function() yourself. Because you can just stack operations up and build a dynamic graph. It's however a sensible idea to bunch these operations together. If any operation involves trainable parameters (for example a linear layer of a neural network), you should subclass `nn.Module()` and bunch your operations together in the forward method. This allows you to easily access parameters (as outlined above) for use of `torch.optim`, etc. If you don't have any trainable parameters, I would probably still bunch them together, but a standard Python function, where you take care of the instantination of each operation you use would be sufficient.

If you have a new custom operation (e.g. a new stochastic layer with some complicated sampling procedure), you should subclass `Function()` and define `__init__(), forward()` and `backward()` to tell PyTorch how to compute results and how to compute gradients, when you use this operation. Afterwards, you should either create a functional version to take care of instantinating the function and use your operation or create a module, if your operation has trainable parameters. Again, you can read more about this in the link above.

Comment: good answer thank you. I do not understand one thing, this sentence:  just bunch them together in a function, where you take part of the instantination of each operation.

1. I assume "function" means the python function, not torch Function?

2. This I just cannot understand the meaning:  "where you take part of the instantination of each operation."

Comment: 1. Yes, exactly. With bunch them together I meant a python function which you use as a wrapper. This is because all subclasses of `torch.autograd.Function` are CLASSES. So you need to first create an instance of them, before you can use them. Suppose you implemented class My_OP(torch.autograd.Function): ..... , you would use it like this: My_OP()(input). Especially, when the operation takes parameters to be initialised, it's more convenient to put that in a Pyhton function, i.e. def my_op(input): return My_OP()(input). This is also well-explained in the link above. 2. Meant take care not part